# How to install pygame on el capitan

Tags: python, pygame, osx-elcapitan

I wrote a bunch of code for a game in python using pygame, but I cannot figure how to get pygame to work for the life of me. This is the error message that I get when I attempt to run it in terminal.

```
~$  python dodger.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dodger.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame, random, sys
ImportError: No module named pygame`
```

Comment: How did you install `pygame`? And much more interesting: how did you manage to write "a bunch of code" if pygame is not installed? No testing?

Answer (score 0):

It may be that `pygame` is not linked to `PYTHONPATH`.

To check, run this in an interpreter:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.path
```

If `pygame` is not there, then you need to add it. Sometimes reinstalling and using the default directory might do the trick. If not, follow this tutorial:

http://www.bdnyc.org/2012/09/editing-pythonpath-to-import-modules/

They show you how to do it in an easy and concise manner.

Best of luck, and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Installing Pygame on El Capitan has some gotchas.  It's not clear whether you've installed it properly, or it's a path problem as the other answer suggests, so I'll include the correct install procedure here:

http://kidscancode.org/blog/2015/09/pygame_install/

These steps will install Pygame via homebrew, and are the most reliable procedure I've found.

The other problem you will have once Pygame is working is that images will be corrupted due to a bug/incompatibility with the latest version of SDL_image.  You will have to downgrade SDL_image to 1.2.10 as described here:

https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/issues/284/max-osx-el-capitan-using-the-deprecated